# Can I XSS cross site script from a google chrome app?

Tags: google-chrome, scripting, xss

I would like to make a google chrome app (packaged) that can XSS. I have tried adding permission patterns and explicit URLs, tabs, and content_script matching rules to the app manifest. None work. I don't want a 'hack' to allow XSS, as google could fix that.

EDIT: Yes, this is for a legitimate app. I'm making a remote control tool for devices with IPs that are mutually trusted. I'm coming from a desktop programming background to make a web version of a certain product. I'm wondering if a chrome app has permissions like a desktop app would, which can be approved on install, and then allow the app to do what's covered in those permissions.

Comment: So...you want black hat advice on stackoverflow? Or am I missing something?

Comment: Like most security vulnerabilities XSS has legitimate uses too.